# How to pass an popup from Android when sending SMS ?

Tags: android, sms

I need to make an application for warranty online, means mobile phones from end user will auto send an SMS to our company server (SMS Content is IMEI get from code) when duration time reach 15 minutes This SMS will be record to my server and end user can go for warranty without any paper. But I have an problem, phone display an popup warning.

> [image]

I search and know this is android warning and can not remove this popup.
But can anyone give me a suggest :

1. Display popup and auto select "Send" button ( Can do this ?)
2. Request manufacture give an firmware not display popup with sending SMS to my gateway ( can manufacture do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a security measure which is part of the Android OS. Unless you're making your own ROM (your own version of Android OS), there's no getting rid of it and nor should there be.

Comment: Thanks , I will ask company request manufacture to customize ROM